# How to relate the coordinates of a lab-frame observer and an uniformly accelerating observer?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, unruh-effect

If there is lab-frame observer with coordinates $(t,x)$ and a **uniformly** acceletaing observer in  $1+1$ dimensional flat Minkowski spacetime with coordinates $(t',x')$, can we analytically relate $(t',x')$ and $(t',x')$ i.e. express $t=t(t',x')$ and $x=x(t',x')$?

Comment: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but isn't this just [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates)?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0601179

Comment: @NiharKarve Thanks, but how will you derive this transformation? I can integrate $\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}=a^\mu=(0,a)$ where $a$ is the (constant magnitude of the 3-acceleration) to find that $t(\tau)=a^{-1}(\sinh(a\tau)$ and $x(\tau)=a^{-1}\cosh(a\tau))$. But in my way of doing it, I can relate $t$ to **only** $\tau$

Comment: @mithusengupta123 I think your solutions are nearly correct (I think you might have forgotten an arbitrary constant after integration for $x(\tau)$, but it's been a while so I'm not sure.). Not sure I see the problem... Of course, to get to the Rindler coordinates you'll need to do a little more manipulation, defining an instantaneous rest frame, etc...

Comment: @Philip "to get to the Rindler coordinates you'll need to do a little more manipulation, defining an instantaneous rest frame" Can you suggest a reference? I do not know how to do that. Thanks

Comment: @mithusengupta123 Check out [this simple paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0601179) on arXiv, it explains how to do it. If I remember right, the quantities like $a$ which are "constants" start to become position dependent in the instantaneous rest frame. The linked paper doesn't seem to mention Rindler coordinates specifically, but I believe the approach is similar.